# Replace k-th to n-th characters in 1st line and last line using bash?

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I want to replace some characters in header and footer of a file. If say, I want to replace 5th to 9th character how do I do it? I need to use bash or a shell command.

I want to do something like this

```
s="abcdabcd"
s=s=s[0]+"12"+s[4:]
>a12dabcd
```

I have a string of exact length I can substitute and the start and end of replacement. I want to put the generated replacement back into the file.

Example:

I have this header:

HEADER  22aabbccdd23aabbccdd

I get these start and end indices : 2,10

I get this string: xyz56789

I want this: HEADER 22xyz5678923aabbccdd

to replace the existing 1st line in the file.

Comment: post a testable input lines and describe, replacement rules and post the expected result

Comment: I have posted an example @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: Your examples don't match each other (or the textual description). Please post a real example.

Comment: PS: In my answer I've chosen to mimic the sample input/output of your first example. I've ignored the `4:` part (because it makes no sense) as well as the "5th to 9th character" part of the description, and I have no idea what that `HEADER` string is doing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Perl:

```
perl -i -lpe 'if ($. == 1 || eof) { substr($_, 1, 2) = "12" }' input.txt
```

- `-i`: modify file in place
- `-l`: automatically strip newlines from input and add them back on output
- `-p`: iterate over lines of the input file and print them back out
- `-e CODE`: what to do for each line

First we check whether the current line number (`$.`) is 1 (i.e. we're processing the first line of the file) or we have reached the end of the file (i.e. the line currently being processed is the last line of the file). If the condition is true, we take the substring of the current line (`$_`) starting from offset 1  of length 2 and set it to `"12"`.

Comment: Your answer works, guess I need to get better at english. That header string is simply an example string in which I need to replace a substring. I have a start index and a non-inclusive end-index, and a replacement string ready. I just needed to find out how to this to a file's 1st line inplace

Answer (score 0):

Simply with `sed`:

*input.txt:*

```
$ cat input.txt
22aabbccdd23aabbccdd
asasdfsdfd234234234234
```

---

```
$ sed -Ei '1 s/(..).{8}/\1xyz56789/' input.txt
```

Result:

```
22xyz5678923aabbccdd
asasdfsdfd234234234234
```

Comment: @melpomene, for now - yes, because there's a mismatching between title and the last sentence **to replace the existing 1st line in the file.**